# Excel for each row containg value, check if other cell is true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm stuck with the following.
I'm cleaning up an account database and need to see if a parent account has active children.
All accounts that haven't had any transaction since 1 year should be deactivated unless there are active child accounts.

The layout is like this:

[image]

So in this case, the 1001 acme parent account has one active subaccount.
I tried a number of things but couldn't find a solution, in fact I'm really clueless.
I think I should combine Countifs with some Vlookup filter, but it should find all rows that contain the paren account number and check if they are flagged as active or not

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,A2,E:E,"Yes")>0,"Subaccount exists","Not found")`

Comment: Are subaccounts with no transactions since 1 year supposed to be deactivated as well? Should it affect it's parent account as well?

Comment: Can subaccounts have their own subaccounts as well?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than explaining `COUNTIFS()`, please review the syntax: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function

`=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,A2,E:E,"Yes")>0,"Subaccount exists","Not found")`

[image]